# Use jtc (or shell) to build key/value pairs from json where element1 is key and element 2 is value

Tags: json, bash, shell, jtc

Given this json

```
[
   {"name" : "Steve", "id" : "25"},
   {"name" : "Joe",   "id" : "36"}

]
```

How can I use jtc (or other shell thing) to get output like this? (Or output suitable for processing to get this)

```
Steve : 25
Joe : 26
```

I can pull the value for a given element with a basic `jtc -w'<name>'` but when I try to build that out I go nowhere.

Comment: You might have a look at using jq:  https://jqlang.github.io/jq/

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is:

```
# with json string as variable named 'my_json'

paste -d ' ' <(echo ${my_json} |jq -r '.[].name' | awk '{print $1":"}') <(echo ${my_json} | jq -r '.[].id')
```

```
# with data store in json file named 'my.json'

paste -d ' ' <(jq -r '.[].name' <my.json | awk '{print $1":"}') <(jq -r '.[].id' <my.json)
```

- These commands extract keys then append with `:` by `awk`, and append the rest values with given json.
- The 'append' method is done by `paste` command with delimiters=  (not default `\t`)

result:

```
Steve: 25
Joe: 36
```

Maybe there would be a more elegant solution with pure `jq`.

#### note

1. To install `jq`: check [here](https://command-not-found.com/jq)
2. If you want adjust spaces around the colon `:`, change `awk`:

```
paste -d ' ' <(jq -r '.[].name' <my.json | awk '{print $1"  :  "}') <(jq -r '.[].id' <my.json)

# result
Steve  :   25
Joe  :   36
```

3. `paste` in tab `\t` and without colon `:`

```
paste <(jq -r '.[].name' <my.json) <(jq -r '.[].id' <my.json)

# result
Steve   25
Joe     36
```